# $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0$ implies $f$ attains its maximum value

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If we suppose that $f$ is a positive continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0$. I want to show that $f$ attains its maximum value.

Comment: First choose a  closed ball, $B$, about $0$ so that $\Vert f\Vert$ is at most $\Vert f(0)\Vert$ on $B^C$.

Comment: It mentions something along the lines of considering "for all epsilon > 0, there is an N so that abs(f(x)) < epsilon for all x with norm of x > N........

Answer (score 0):

Take $M=f(0)/2$. By hypothesis $\exists R>0$ s.t. $f(x)\le M$ when $\|x\|>R$. The ball $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\,\vert\,\|x\|\le R\}$ is compact...

Comment: This is all I would need to show? @Martin-BlasPerezPinilla

Comment: @juniormath, can you continue after the "..."?

Comment: would it be it is compact because it is closed and bounded? I really don't know how to do these problems @Martin-BlasPerezPinilla

Comment: @juniormath, right. What can do say about the maximum of $f$ in the ball? (hint: 0 is in the ball)